# airflow worker crashing in helms upgrade with Temporary failure in name resolution for postgres

Tags: docker, airflow, kubernetes-helm, minikube

I have been trying to use a custom dockerfile for mounting dags and plugins as follows:

```
FROM apache/airflow:2.3.0-python3.7
COPY ./dags/ /opt/airflow/dags/
COPY ./plugins/ /opt/airflow/plugins/docker push
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 5555
```

which I am building as:

```
docker build -f base.dockerfile --pull --tag lqc-airflow:0.0.1 .
minikube image load lqc-airflow:0.0.1
```

and then doing a `helm install`

```
helm upgrade $RELEASE_NAME apache-airflow/airflow --namespace $NAMESPACE --set images.airflow.repository=lqc-airflow --set images.airflow.tag=0.0.1
```

which however is making just the `airflow-worker-0` pod fail due to the following error:

```
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/bin/airflow", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/__main__.py", line 38, in main
    args.func(args)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/cli/cli_parser.py", line 51, in command
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/cli.py", line 99, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/cli/commands/celery_command.py", line 130, in worker
    session = celery_app.backend.ResultSession()
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/backends/database/__init__.py", line 109, in ResultSession
    **self.engine_options)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/backends/database/session.py", line 88, in session_factory
    self.prepare_models(engine)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/backends/database/session.py", line 72, in prepare_models
    ResultModelBase.metadata.create_all(engine)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py", line 4745, in create_all
    ddl.SchemaGenerator, self, checkfirst=checkfirst, tables=tables
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3007, in _run_ddl_visitor
    with self.begin() as conn:
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2923, in begin
    conn = self.connect(close_with_result=close_with_result)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3095, in connect
    return self._connection_cls(self, close_with_result=close_with_result)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 91, in __init__
    else engine.raw_connection()
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3174, in raw_connection
    return self._wrap_pool_connect(self.pool.connect, _connection)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3145, in _wrap_pool_connect
    e, dialect, self
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2004, in _handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection
    sqlalchemy_exception, with_traceback=exc_info[2], from_=e
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 211, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3141, in _wrap_pool_connect
    return fn()
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 301, in connect
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 755, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 419, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 259, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 247, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 362, in __init__
    self.__connect(first_connect_check=True)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 605, in __connect
    pool.logger.debug("Error on connect(): %s", e)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 72, in __exit__
    with_traceback=exc_tb,
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 211, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 599, in __connect
    connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py", line 578, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 583, in connect
    return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not translate host name "postgres" to address: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

I am just following the reading advisory from airflow: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/helm-chart/stable/manage-dags-files.html

please note that there are no such name resolution errors if I dont use my custom docker file. Kindly help!

Comment: did you check if the chart creates a postgres db deployment?

Comment: yes it does- like `airflow-postgresql.airflow` is also pingable from inside all kubernetes pods of the `airflow` namespace. just that airflow.cfg is like:
```
result_backend = db+postgresql://postgres:airflow@postgres/airflow
```

Comment: what about `sql_alchemy_conn` in airflow.cfg?

Comment: it is all the same- I have the helm release installation w/o the custom dockerfile to be working just fine. the problem shows up only on using a custom dockerfile. 
anyways the value for both the places:
`sql_alchemy_conn = sqlite:////opt/airflow/airflow.db`

Answer (score 0):

thanks @Hussein also for your support, but I could solve it by myself. I saw that the logs of the `airflow-migrations` pods, complaint of a revision id not being found. So somehow I chanced upon: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/migrations-ref.html
and there I saw the airflow tag which was above/carrying that alembic revision.
My revision id was `ecb43d2a1842` and thus the changes to my docker file were:

```
FROM apache/airflow:2.4.3
COPY ./dags/ /opt/airflow/dags/
COPY ./plugins/ /opt/airflow/plugins/
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

thus `2.4.3` was the catch.